# Огромный JSON и PHP

Tags: json, php

Доброго времени суток.
Возникла маленькая проблема с разбором большущего JSON-а с помощью php.
Что делалось с моей стороны:

```
$trash_json = file_get_contents("http://activex.gurtam.com/?a=login&u=wialon_test&p=test"); //шлем GET с параметрами
echo $trash_json; // Вижу большой json 
$j_arr= json_decode($trash_json,true); // пытаюсь превратить его в массив
var_dump($j_arr); // Пусто :(
```

По итогу - $j_array - пустой :(
не могу понять в чем причина. Народ, помогите, пожалуйста, буду весьма благодарен.

P.S. JSON сюда не кидал - большой. Чтобы его получить - http://activex.gurtam.com/?a=login&u=wialon_test&p=test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Шурик - я на это намекал :)
Вобщем, решил проблему написанием функции, которая исправит мне ошибки с оберткой элементов json-а:

```
function kost_json_decode($json) {
    $json = substr($json, 1, strlen($json) - 2);
    $json = preg_replace("/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+?):/" , "\"$1\":", $json);
    $output = json_decode("{".$json."}",true);
    return ($output);
}
```

Так что если у кого возникнут вопросы - пользуйтесь :) Помогает.

Answer (score 0):

У вас json не валидный. возьмите имена в кавычки. `{'name':'value'}`

**Добавлено.**

Попробуйте так:

```
$trash_json = '{code: "ERROR", txt: "Already authorized"}'; //шлем GET с параметрами
$trash_json = preg_replace('/([{,])(\s*)([^"]+?)\s*:/','$1"$3":',$trash_json);
echo $trash_json; // Вижу большой json 
$j_arr= json_decode($trash_json,true); // пытаюсь превратить его в массив
var_dump($j_arr); //
```

Ну, и почитать [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php), если такое решение не подходит.

Comment: Спасибо, но формирую его не я...Приходится работать с тем, что есть :(

Comment: См. добавление.

Answer (score 0):

```
php -r 'var_dump( json_decode( file_get_contents( "http://activex.gurtam.com/?a=login&u=wialon_test&p=test" ) ) ); echo "\n".json_last_error()."\n";'
NULL

4
```

код ошибки: 4 - это JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX